# Does the Javascript regex pattern \W include spaces?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using this expression: `/\W+/g` to match all characters that are not numbers, letters and spaces. It seems to be including spaces. How would I build a regex that did not include spaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/[^a-z0-9\s]+/ig
```

Explanation:

```
[^   Character class which matches characters NOT in the following class
a-z  All lowercase letters of the alphabet
0-9  All numbers
\s   Whitespace characters
]    End of the character class

i   Case-insensitivity to match uppercase letters
```

Comment: thanks, my guess is that I was not clear enough in my question, but all I needed to add to yours was `\s` so what I found to work was `/[^a-z0-9\s]+/ig`

Comment: This regex still matches spaces, I think you want something like /[^a-z0-9\s]+/ig

Comment: @chromedude: I'm glad it's working for you. Fixed answer for clarity.

Comment: @Tim Cooper - the regex still does not match spaces!

Comment: However, this works: /[^0-9a-zA-Z]/g as per this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24062304/3062486

Answer (score 2):

A more accurate wording for `\W` is **any Non-Alphanumeric character**. 
`\s` is for **Any Whitespace**.

So, it would be something like this:
[^\s]

Answer (score 0):

`\W` means "non-word characters", the inverse of `\w`, so it will match spaces as well. I'm a bit surprised it doesn't match numbers, though.