# Remove all non alphanumeric and any white spaces in string using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to remove any non alphanumeric characters ANY white spaces from a string.

Currently I have a two step solution and would like to make it in to one.

```
var name_parsed = name.replace(/[^0-9a-zA-Z ]/g, ''); // Bacon, Juice | 234
name_parsed = name_parsed.replace(/ /g,'')
console.log(name_parsed); //BaconJuice234
```

Could someone let me know how to achieve above in one execution and not two?

Comment: You include a whitespace in the original regular expression!

Comment: @epascarello oh geez...No wonder I tried and tried! Thank you.

Comment: Why not just `replace(/\W+/g, '')`

Comment: @adeneo Because `\w` includes `_` as well.

Comment: @VisioN - true, there's the underscore, but as long as the string doesn't contain an underscore it's not an issue. Was just a suggestion really !

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Remove the space from the first set and will do the job:

```
name.replace(/[^0-9a-zA-Z]/g, '');
```

You may read this code as *"remove all characters that are not digits (`[0-9]`) and alpha characters (`[a-zA-Z]`)"*.

Alternatively, you can use the i flag to make your regular expression ignore case. Then the code can be simplified:

```
name.replace(/[^0-9a-z]/gi, '');
```

Comment: @VisioN this doesn't work for me in the following example: 
"sdf234 234dfsf".replace(/[^0-9a-zA-Z]/g, '')
I just did this in Firebug console, not sure why it wouldn't work.   
Result = "sdf234234dfsf"

Comment: @Jacques What exactly doesn't work? To your result it works as expected: it removed all characters apart from digits and Latin letters.